# Solve the indefinite integral of ${\sqrt{x}\arctan\sqrt{x}\over 1+x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int {\sqrt{x}\arctan\sqrt{x}\over 1+x}dx$$

I tried a substituition of $x=t^2$, then doing it by parts. It didn't go too well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with $t^2 = x,$  you have $$\int \frac{t\tan^{-1} t}{1+t^2} 2t\, dt = 2 \int \left(1 - \frac 1{1+t^2}\right)\tan^{-1}t \, dt=2\int\tan^{-1}t \, dt-\left(\tan^{-1}t\right)^2 $$

an integration by parts gives $$\int \tan^{-1}t\, dt= t \tan^{-1}t - \int\frac{t}{1+t^2}\, dt
=  t \tan^{-1}t-\frac 12\ln(1+t^2) + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $\sqrt{x}=t$. Then $dx=2tdt$ and the integral becomes
$\int \frac{2t^2\arctan t}{1+t^2}dt=
\int \frac{2(1+t^2)-2}{1+t^2}\arctan t\, dt=
\int 2\arctan t\,dt-2\int \frac{\arctan t}{1+t^2}dt=
2t \arctan t-\int \frac{2t}{1+t^2}-(\arctan t)^2=
2t \arctan t-\log(1+t^2)+(\arctan t)^2+c= 
2\sqrt{x} \arctan\sqrt{x}-\log(1+x)+(\arctan\sqrt{x})^2+c$

Comment: Thanks for trying to use MathJax; I've edited your answer to correct some formatting errors. Check the source (by clicking [edit]) to see how it works. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).